# Sort table containing groups using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML table:

```html
 <table border="1" id="myTable">        
    <tr><td><b>Group1</b></td><td><b>Group3</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>value1</td><td>value1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value3</td><td>value4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value4</td><td>value5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value5</td><td>value2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Group2</b></td><td><b>Group2</b></td></tr>
     <tr><td>value1</td><td>value1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value3</td><td>value4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value4</td><td>value5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value5</td><td>value2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Group3</b></td><td><b>Group1</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>value1</td><td>value1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value3</td><td>value4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value4</td><td>value5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value5</td><td>value2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I tried this, put it first in a dictionary and then put it in the table. To understand the code below, I am trying to sort the groups by the `<b>` tag, from there I put this tag as a key in the dictionary because it is a group and I place the respective items of that group in the dictionary key `{}`

```
sortTable($('#myTable'), 'asc', 0)

function sortTable(tbl, order, column){
  var table = $(tbl)
  var rows = table.find('tr')
  var groups = {}

  rows.each(function(i, e){
    var cells = $(this).find('td')
    var cell = $(cells[column])
    var lastGroup = ''

    if (cell.find('b').length > 0){
      if (!groups[cells.text()]){
        groups[cell.text()] = []  
        lastGroup = cell.text()      
      }     
    }
    groups[lastGroup].push(cell.text())    
  })
  groups = groups.sort()

  rows.each(function(i, e){
    var cells = $(this).find('td').text(groups[i])
  })
}
```

I need to sort the groups in this table and the items in this group. Ascending or Descending.

How do I do this in jQuery?

Comment: What have you achieved? Show us some code and where are you stuck.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I posted what I tried, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Datatables** JS plugin

[Default ordering (sorting)](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
});});
```